# Inner for loop in nested for loop in handlebars is not working

Tags: handlebars.js, nested-loops, each, handlebarshelper

My outer for loop is working and printing name but inner loop in which i'm trying to iterate through systems is not working.

```
var executions = [    
    {
        name:'Password',
        email:'p@pol.com',
        systems: [
           {system: 'PME1'},
           {system: 'PME2'},
           {system: 'PME2'},
        ],
        
    }
];
```

```
{#each executions}}  
  <span>Name : {{name}}</span>
    <table>
     <tbody>
      {{#each systems}}
      <tr>
       <td>
        <p>{{ system }}</p>
       </td>
      </tr>
     {{/each}}
    </tbody>
   </table>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: The code you have provided looks just fine to me. See: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/84vjnLg9/

Comment: I faced the same issue and got my solution in using names for iterated data
More here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77230516/handlebars-js-nested-each-doent-work/77231893#77231893