# Handlebars.js: nested {{#each}} doen't work

Tags: node.js, express-handlebars

> Note: I'm using `express-handlebars`

My test data for render: `data: [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6] ]`;

My `.hbs` tempalte:

```
{{#each data}}
  <div>
  {{#each inner}}
    inside - {{this}}
  {{/each}}
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

Outer `#each`  works just fine, but the inner is acting like there is no data to render.

I've looked into similar questions/examples, all are using the same syntax.

There are no errors and in others ways hb works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to use names for `#each` variables:

```
<div>
  {{#each data as |nums|}}
    {{#each nums as |num|}}
      <div>! {{num}} </div>
    {{/each}}
  {{/each}}
</div>
```